# Números más cercanos entre sublistas en listas separadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Entre sublistas de listas A Y B, ¿cómo puedo encontrar los valores más cercanos? considerando que la diferencia de estos sea menor a 4 y de ser así,
reemplazar el valor en la sublista de lista B por el encontrado en la sublista de la lista A, pero si la diferencia es mayor que 4, conservar el numero original que está en sublista de lista B.

```
A = [[296,393,495,662,781],[1175,1320]]
B = [[293,331,390,492],[1174,1319]]

z = [[]]

for a,b in zip(A, B):
    for c in a:
        for k, e in enumerate(b):
            if abs(c - e) < 4:
                z[0].insert(k,c)
            else:
                z[0].insert(k,e)

z
```

> Resultado deseado: 
>   z = [[296,331,393,495],[1175,1320]]
>
> Resultado obtenido:
>   z = [[1174,1320,1175,1319,293,331,390,492,293,331,390,492,293,331,390,495,293,331,393,492,296,331,390,492]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás iterando al completo sobre la sublista `b`  por cada elemento de la sublista `a`. Además insertas siempre los elemento en la única sublista que defines para `z`.

Suponiendo que tengas siempre dos listas con listas de enteros anidadas y que ambas tienen exactamente la misma estructura, basta con que uses `zip` también sobre las parejas de sublistas que retorna el primer `for`:

```
A = [[296,393,495,662,781],[1175,1320]]
B = [[293,331,390,492],[1174,1319]]

z = []

for subl_a, subl_b in zip(A, B):
    sublist = []
    for item_a, item_b in zip(subl_a, subl_b):
        if abs(item_a - item_b) < 4:
            sublist.append(item_a)
        else:
            sublist.append(item_b)
    z.append(sublist)
```

Otra opción es trabajar sobre una copia de la lista `B`:

```
A = [[296,393,495,662,781],[1175,1320]]
B = [[293,331,390,492],[1174,1319]]

z = [sublist[:] for sublist in B]

for i, (subl_a, subl_b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
    for j, (item_a, item_b) in enumerate(zip(subl_a, subl_b)):
        if abs(item_a - item_b) < 4:
            z[i][j] = item_a
```

Se puede usar también `copy.deepcopy()`para generar la copia  pero esto copiaría también los objetos `int` por lo que es menos eficiente, dado que `int` es inmutable su no copia no es un problema. En términos generales, en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución, va a ser algo más lenta que la primera opción por  la iteración extra, no obstante si la listas `A` y `B` tiene pocos elementos pero sus sublistas son extensas la diferencia puede ser residual o invertirse si hay muy pocas substituciones.

Si verdaderamente es prioritario reducir el tiempo de ejecución podemos utilizar la primera aproximación pero usando listas por compresión con lo que se obtendrá una reducción de en torno al 8%, a costa de perder seguramente legibilidad:

```
A = [[296,393,495,662,781],[1175,1320]]
B = [[293,331,390,492],[1174,1319]]

z = [[item_a if abs(item_a - item_b) < 4 else item_b
          for item_a, item_b in zip(subl_a, subl_b)]
              for subl_a, subl_b in zip(A, B)]
```

En ambos casos obtenemos:

> ```
> >>> z
> [[296, 331, 390, 492], [1175, 1320]]
> ```